# Can MVC's ValidateRequest be triggered in code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handle validation failures myself in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983322/handle-validation-failures-myself-in-asp-net-mvc)

I have an action method that takes HTML input (potentially).

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cms(string pageContent)
{
   CmsData = pageContent;
   return Redirect("/home/cms");
}
```

So I don't want the dreaded "a potentially dangerous request..." error to crash the POST. So I set `ValidateInput = false` above.

However, I would like to then execute that same check in code and react to it (like post a message saying HTML is not allowed) rather than crashing.

I know I could run some sort of code black-list check, but I'd rather not. I'd rather just have MVC tell me, but without fully crashing the page and let me handle the error messages.

Easy? Possible?

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983322/handle-validation-failures-myself-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question is about dynamically calling the `RequestValidator` to know whether the value doesn't contain any html. It is not easy! the reason is the method `IsValidRequestString` of `RequestValidator` that does the check is **protected internal virtual** and so you can't just invoke it outside but by creating a custom [`RequestValidator`](http://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/creating-your-own-custom-request-validation/) you may achieve that (you may have to create a public method that call the protected one).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I wonder if a little reflection to access that protected internal might just do the trick. Will see...